# I am trying to upload a profile image within my Laravel 8 application. I however keep getting "Attempt to read property "image" on array" error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save/upload a profile image in my Laravel 8 application.
I am using the stock controller "UpdateUserProfileInformation.update" in Laravel Fortify
I however keep getting this error

ErrorException
Attempt to read property "image" on array

View

```
...
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('user-profile-information.update') }}">
                    @csrf
                    @method('PUT')
...
<input class="file-upload d-none" type="file" accept="image/*" id="image" name="image" />
...
```

Controller

```
public function update($user, array $input)
    {
        ...
            $fileName = time().'.'.$input['image'];
            $input->image->move(public_path('uploads'), $fileName);
    ...
```

Obviously my issue is that i am trying to save an array, but I can't figure out how to isolate this single file.

Comment: I've also tried "$path = $input->file('image')->store('tickets');" in the controller, but I get this error "Call to a member function store() on string"

Comment: Why are you using a array instead of a Request object for your POST data?

Comment: Hi Gert B, it's the stock controller "UpdateUserProfileInformation.update" in Laravel Fortify, and has other stuff it the controller. Wish i could change it to $request, but that breaks all the updating of user functionality in fortify.

Comment: In PHP, the arrow ```->``` is the accessor used for objects, while ```[]``` is used for arrays, such as your ```$input``` argument. I don't know exactly what the argument contains, but to access for example the ``ìmage`` index, you would have to write ```$input["image"]```.

Comment: Hi Kyrre, I agree with you, I also tried $path = $input['image']->store('dir');  in the controller, which I thought would work, but got the error "
Call to a member function store() on string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when working with files in form you should add an enctype

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
```

Comment: Thanks @Rick W, that worked a treat. I totally forgot about enctype, you probaly saved me days trying to figure this out. Awesome! Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in form tag when working with file

Replace

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('user-profile-information.update') }}">
```

With

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('user-profile-information.update') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks Jigneshsinh Rathod, yes that worked. @Rick W just beat you to answering the question. Thanks for your help guys.